# helm deployments over kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

Say for example I have rendered all the manifests of a tool called cert-manager and I have deployed in kubernetes environment using kustomize, If I want to perform an upgrade version of cert-manager through helm, How do I do that??

Answer (score 1):

You can just run the command

```
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
```

update the variable or value you would like to change

```
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --create-namespace \
  --version v1.7.1 \
  # --set installCRDs=true
```

make sure you use the **same name** of **deployment** or **stateful** sets, so accordingly PODs or deployment will get rolled out.

i think, the cert-manager does not use the **PVC** or **PV** so nothing worry about the **Read Write Many**.

Ref doc : https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/